# How to print DateTime variable in the RAISERROR method?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, raiserror

My Stored Procedure accepts two params
 @EffectiveStartDate DATETIME
 @EffectiveEndDate DATETIME

I wrote the validation code as this:

```
IF(@EffectiveStartDate > @EffectiveEndDate)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('SPName: InsertUpdateLiquidityDateRule:  Start Date: %s cannot  be greater than End Date %s',11,1,CAST(@EffectiveStartDate AS varchar(30)),CAST(@EffectiveEndDate AS varchar(30)));
            RETURN -1
        END
```

May I know what am I doing wrong here.

While Compiling my SProc, it raised the message 'Incorrect syntax near CAST()'

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The supplied value must be a constant or a variable. You cannot specify a function name as a parameter value. (from MSDN [Executing Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx)).

You need to do something like this:

```
declare @EffectiveStartDateText varchar(30)
set @EffectiveStartDateText = cast(@EffectiveStartDate as varchar)

declare @EffectiveEndDateText varchar(30)
set @EffectiveEndDateText = cast(@EffectiveEndDate as varchar)

RAISERROR (
    'SPName: InsertUpdateLiquidityDateRule:  Start Date: %s cannot  be greater than End Date %s',
    11,
    1,
    @EffectiveStartDateText,
    @EffectiveEndDateText);
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "You cannot specify a function name as a parameter value."  All i tried was an explicit cast of datetime sproc parameter to a varchar. Are Stored Proc parameters treated differently than locally declared variables?

Comment: CAST is a function. While supplied parameter for stored procedure cannot be function. Quote from the spec: "The supplied value must be a constant or a variable. You cannot specify a function name as a parameter value." So you need to make a variable to be able to use in a proc.

Comment: This is a way to make the date to string conversion more compact:               
DECLARE  @strStart_Orig VARCHAR(30) = CAST(@strStart_Orig AS VARCHAR)

Answer (score 4):

The docs for [FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql) say "For more information about the placeholders allowed in error messages and the editing process, see [RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)." This really seems to imply that RAISERROR should work the same way as FORMATMESSAGE.

Since you can use CONVERT (but not CAST) in the parameters of FORMATMESSAGE, if the implication were true then you could use CONVERT in the parameters of RAISERROR, which would allow for a sweet and elegant one-liner.

But SQL Server doesn't work (the way you expect). However, at least it can be made a bit simpler: you only have to declare one variable, not two:

```sql
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @ErrorMessage= FORMATMESSAGE('SPName: InsertUpdateLiquidityDateRule:  Start Date: %s cannot  be greater than End Date %s',
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(30), @EffectiveStartDate, 23),
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(30), @EffectiveEndDate, 23)
    );

RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 11, 1);
```

(SQL Server 2016 SP2-CU12)

[Erland Sommarskog](http://sommarskog.se/index.html) (SQL Server MVP since 2001) nicely sums it up [here](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html): "I get the feeling that SQL Server is intentionally designed to be as confusing as possible". And "if you at some point runs *[sic]* for the door screaming Oracle, come back, everything is forgiven, I can't hardly blame you".

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help out, here is another example. 
I put this in the BEGIN CATCH statement after my BEGIN TRY.

Note: This is very similar to using an if statement.

```
BEGIN TRY
--Do something.
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
    --Else on error do this.
    PRINT 'Problem found!!! ' 

    -- Whoops, there was an error
    -- Raise an error with the details of the exception
    DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), 
            @ErrSeverity int, 
            @ErrLineNum int

    SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
           @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
           @ErrLineNum = ERROR_LINE()

    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1, @ErrLineNum)

END CATCH
```

Comment: This is an answer to a different question, but not to the question on this page :)